# Fontawesome fonts not loading using Aurelia, with Scss, and webpack

Tags: webpack, sass, font-awesome, aurelia, bulma

So I have [this project](https://github.com/xenoterracide/capacitor-android-issue-repro/tree/topic/css) where I'm using Aurelia, Bulma, Scss, Fontawesome and Webpack. I've installed both Bulma and FontAwesome with yarn. The stylesheets for both appear intact.

Here's my [`app.html`](https://github.com/xenoterracide/capacitor-android-issue-repro/blob/topic/css/src/app.html), everything seems to work right except the [`fas fa-plus` icon](https://github.com/xenoterracide/capacitor-android-issue-repro/blob/topic/css/src/app.html#L10).

```html
    <template>
      <require from="./styles.scss"></require>
      <section class="section">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="tabs">
            <ul>
              <li class="is-active"><a>Active Tab</a></li>
              <li>
                <a>
                  <span class="icon is-small"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fas fa-plus"></i></span>
                  <span>Add a tab</span>
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <article class="media">
            <figure class="media-left">
              <p class="image is-64x64">
                <img src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/128x128.png">
              </p>
            </figure>
            <div class="media-content">
              <p>My List</p>
            </div>
          </article>
        </div>
      </section>
    </template>
```

in my [`styles.scss`](https://github.com/xenoterracide/capacitor-android-issue-repro/blob/topic/css/src/styles.scss) I have this

```
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free";
@import "~bulma";

$fa-font-path: "../webfonts";
```

and lastly here's my [`webpack.config.js`](https://github.com/xenoterracide/capacitor-android-issue-repro/blob/topic/css/webpack.config.js) which is just what aurelia generated.

```js
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const DuplicatePackageCheckerPlugin = require('duplicate-package-checker-webpack-plugin');
const project = require('./aurelia_project/aurelia.json');
const { AureliaPlugin, ModuleDependenciesPlugin } = require('aurelia-webpack-plugin');
const { ProvidePlugin } = require('webpack');
const { BundleAnalyzerPlugin } = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

// config helpers:
const ensureArray = (config) => config && (Array.isArray(config) ? config : [config]) || [];
const when = (condition, config, negativeConfig) =>
  condition ? ensureArray(config) : ensureArray(negativeConfig);

// primary config:
const title = 'Aurelia Navigation Skeleton';
const outDir = path.resolve(__dirname, project.platform.output);
const srcDir = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src');
const nodeModulesDir = path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules');
const baseUrl = '/';

const cssRules = [
  { loader: 'css-loader' },
  {
    loader: 'postcss-loader',
    options: { plugins: () => [
      require('autoprefixer')(),
      require('cssnano')()
    ] }
  }
];

const sassRules = [
  {
    loader: "sass-loader",
    options: {
      sassOptions: {
        includePaths: ['node_modules']
      }
    }
  }
];

module.exports = ({ production } = {}, {extractCss, analyze, tests, hmr, port, host } = {}) => ({
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
    modules: [srcDir, 'node_modules'],
    // Enforce single aurelia-binding, to avoid v1/v2 duplication due to
    // out-of-date dependencies on 3rd party aurelia plugins
    alias: { 'aurelia-binding': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/aurelia-binding') }
  },
  entry: {
    app: ['aurelia-bootstrapper']
  },
  mode: production ? 'production' : 'development',
  output: {
    path: outDir,
    publicPath: baseUrl,
    filename: production ? '[name].[chunkhash].bundle.js' : '[name].[hash].bundle.js',
    sourceMapFilename: production ? '[name].[chunkhash].bundle.map' : '[name].[hash].bundle.map',
    chunkFilename: production ? '[name].[chunkhash].chunk.js' : '[name].[hash].chunk.js'
  },
  optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: true,  // separates the runtime chunk, required for long term cacheability
    // moduleIds is the replacement for HashedModuleIdsPlugin and NamedModulesPlugin deprecated in https://github.com/webpack/webpack/releases/tag/v4.16.0
    // changes module id's to use hashes be based on the relative path of the module, required for long term cacheability
    moduleIds: 'hashed',
    // Use splitChunks to breakdown the App/Aurelia bundle down into smaller chunks
    // https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/
    splitChunks: {
      hidePathInfo: true, // prevents the path from being used in the filename when using maxSize
      chunks: "initial",
      // sizes are compared against source before minification
      maxInitialRequests: Infinity, // Default is 3, make this unlimited if using HTTP/2
      maxAsyncRequests: Infinity, // Default is 5, make this unlimited if using HTTP/2
      minSize: 10000, // chunk is only created if it would be bigger than minSize, adjust as required
      maxSize: 40000, // splits chunks if bigger than 40k, adjust as required (maxSize added in webpack v4.15)
      cacheGroups: {
        default: false, // Disable the built-in groups default & vendors (vendors is redefined below)
        // You can insert additional cacheGroup entries here if you want to split out specific modules
        // This is required in order to split out vendor css from the app css when using --extractCss
        // For example to separate font-awesome and bootstrap:
        // fontawesome: { // separates font-awesome css from the app css (font-awesome is only css/fonts)
        //   name: 'vendor.font-awesome',
        //   test:  /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]font-awesome[\\/]/,
        //   priority: 100,
        //   enforce: true
        // },
        // bootstrap: { // separates bootstrap js from vendors and also bootstrap css from app css
        //   name: 'vendor.font-awesome',
        //   test:  /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]bootstrap[\\/]/,
        //   priority: 90,
        //   enforce: true
        // },

        // This is the HTTP/2 optimised cacheGroup configuration
        // generic 'initial/sync' vendor node module splits: separates out larger modules
        vendorSplit: { // each node module as separate chunk file if module is bigger than minSize
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          name(module) {
            // Extract the name of the package from the path segment after node_modules
            const packageName = module.context.match(/[\\/]node_modules[\\/](.*?)([\\/]|$)/)[1];
            return `vendor.${packageName.replace('@', '')}`;
          },
          priority: 20
        },
        vendors: { // picks up everything else being used from node_modules that is less than minSize
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          name: "vendors",
          priority: 19,
          enforce: true // create chunk regardless of the size of the chunk
        },
        // generic 'async' vendor node module splits: separates out larger modules
        vendorAsyncSplit: { // vendor async chunks, create each asynchronously used node module as separate chunk file if module is bigger than minSize
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          name(module) {
            // Extract the name of the package from the path segment after node_modules
            const packageName = module.context.match(/[\\/]node_modules[\\/](.*?)([\\/]|$)/)[1];
            return `vendor.async.${packageName.replace('@', '')}`;
          },
          chunks: 'async',
          priority: 10,
          reuseExistingChunk: true,
          minSize: 5000 // only create if 5k or larger
        },
        vendorsAsync: { // vendors async chunk, remaining asynchronously used node modules as single chunk file
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          name: 'vendors.async',
          chunks: 'async',
          priority: 9,
          reuseExistingChunk: true,
          enforce: true // create chunk regardless of the size of the chunk
        },
        // generic 'async' common module splits: separates out larger modules
        commonAsync: { // common async chunks, each asynchronously used module a separate chunk file if module is bigger than minSize
          name(module) {
            // Extract the name of the module from last path component. 'src/modulename/' results in 'modulename'
            const moduleName = module.context.match(/[^\\/]+(?=\/$|$)/)[0];
            return `common.async.${moduleName.replace('@', '')}`;
          },
          minChunks: 2, // Minimum number of chunks that must share a module before splitting
          chunks: 'async',
          priority: 1,
          reuseExistingChunk: true,
          minSize: 5000 // only create if 5k or larger
        },
        commonsAsync: { // commons async chunk, remaining asynchronously used modules as single chunk file
          name: 'commons.async',
          minChunks: 2, // Minimum number of chunks that must share a module before splitting
          chunks: 'async',
          priority: 0,
          reuseExistingChunk: true,
          enforce: true // create chunk regardless of the size of the chunk
        }
      }
    }
  },
  performance: { hints: false },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: outDir,
    // serve index.html for all 404 (required for push-state)
    historyApiFallback: true,
    hot: hmr || project.platform.hmr,
    port: port || project.platform.port,
    host: host
  },
  devtool: production ? 'nosources-source-map' : 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      // CSS required in JS/TS files should use the style-loader that auto-injects it into the website
      // only when the issuer is a .js/.ts file, so the loaders are not applied inside html templates
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        issuer: [{ not: [{ test: /\.html$/i }] }],
        use: extractCss ? [{
          loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader
        }, ...cssRules
        ] : ['style-loader', ...cssRules]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        issuer: [{ test: /\.html$/i }],
        // CSS required in templates cannot be extracted safely
        // because Aurelia would try to require it again in runtime
        use: cssRules
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: extractCss ? [{
          loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader
        }, ...cssRules, ...sassRules
        ]: ['style-loader', ...cssRules, ...sassRules],
        issuer: /\.[tj]s$/i
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [...cssRules, ...sassRules],
        issuer: /\.html?$/i
      },
      { test: /\.html$/i, loader: 'html-loader' },
      { test: /\.ts$/, loader: "ts-loader" },
      // embed small images and fonts as Data Urls and larger ones as files:
      { test: /\.(png|gif|jpg|cur)$/i, loader: 'url-loader', options: { limit: 8192 } },
      { test: /\.woff2(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/i, loader: 'url-loader', options: { limit: 10000, mimetype: 'application/font-woff2' } },
      { test: /\.woff(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/i, loader: 'url-loader', options: { limit: 10000, mimetype: 'application/font-woff' } },
      // load these fonts normally, as files:
      { test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|otf)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/i, loader: 'file-loader' },
      { test: /environment\.json$/i, use: [
        {loader: "app-settings-loader", options: {env: production ? 'production' : 'development' }},
      ]},
      ...when(tests, {
        test: /\.[jt]s$/i, loader: 'istanbul-instrumenter-loader',
        include: srcDir, exclude: [/\.(spec|test)\.[jt]s$/i],
        enforce: 'post', options: { esModules: true },
      })
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    ...when(!tests, new DuplicatePackageCheckerPlugin()),
    new AureliaPlugin(),
    new ProvidePlugin({
      'Promise': ['promise-polyfill', 'default']
    }),
    new ModuleDependenciesPlugin({
      'aurelia-testing': ['./compile-spy', './view-spy']
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'index.ejs',
      minify: production ? {
        removeComments: true,
        collapseWhitespace: true,
        collapseInlineTagWhitespace: true,
        collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
        removeAttributeQuotes: true,
        minifyCSS: true,
        minifyJS: true,
        removeScriptTypeAttributes: true,
        removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
        ignoreCustomFragments: [/\${.*?}/g]
      } : undefined,
      metadata: {
        // available in index.ejs //
        title, baseUrl
      }
    }),
    // ref: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/mini-css-extract-plugin/
    ...when(extractCss, new MiniCssExtractPlugin({ // updated to match the naming conventions for the js files
      filename: production ? 'css/[name].[contenthash].bundle.css' : 'css/[name].[hash].bundle.css',
      chunkFilename: production ? 'css/[name].[contenthash].chunk.css' : 'css/[name].[hash].chunk.css'
    })),
    ...when(!tests, new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      { from: 'static', to: outDir, ignore: ['.*'] }])), // ignore dot (hidden) files
    ...when(analyze, new BundleAnalyzerPlugin()),
    /**
     * Note that the usage of following plugin cleans the webpack output directory before build.
     * In case you want to generate any file in the output path as a part of pre-build step, this plugin will likely
     * remove those before the webpack build. In that case consider disabling the plugin, and instead use something like
     * `del` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/del), or `rimraf` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/rimraf).
     */
    new CleanWebpackPlugin()
  ]
});
```

My best guess is that the font files aren't be copied out of the node_modules and into the resultant dist directory (or at least not being served by the webpack dev server)

Comment: It's it "fortawesome"? or "fontawesome"? the directory name

Comment: @RobScott `Calebs-MBP:warmaster calebcushing$ ls node_modules/\@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/` https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/using-package-managers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As per documentation](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/using-package-managers#next) you should use the direct path to the css file for the import

```
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free";
```

->

```
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css";
```

EDIT:

To be able to overwrite variables, you would need to import SCSS files instead, like following:

```
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome.scss";
$fa-font-path: "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts";

@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular.scss";
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid.scss";
```

Comment: this works, is it correct though for importing using scss? like I'm guessing the scss variables and such won't work?

Comment: @xenoterracide the variable you set already set (by default) to internal `webfonts` directory, so you do not need to set it. But, if you need to overwrite it with your own webfonts directory, you'd need to import `scss/fontawesome.scss` file instead

Comment: I presume I will want to set some parameters other than the defaults eventually, but when I do that import I'm back to ground 0, and the fonts don't show up (I'm excluding my webfonts path change)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Aurelia CLI and have chosen Webpack and SASS in the custom build options, you don't need to do any of the SASS configuration for font-awesome.

Pull the "css" and "webfonts" folders from the downloaded package from font-awesome site. I put mine in /src/styles/.

Then you just need one tag at the top of your html file.

That's it, they should just work at that point.